# Restlet accepts JSON input from client and respond with POST

Tags: json, rest, maven, jakarta-ee, restlet

I am writing a program which accepts a JSON input with the following format from client:

```
{
    "campaignID": 1,
    "clientID": 1,
    "pmapID": 1,
    "ward": "1-Bedded (Private)",
    "age": 20,
    "attr1": "EXA1(A)",
    "attr2": "EO",
    "attr3": "11/02/2012",
    "attr4": "SIN",
    "attr5": "N",
    "attr6": "Y"
}
```

I'd like to read the JSON input, save all the attributes into local variables (String, int, ...) and finally respond with a POST("JSON") which will return a single float/double value (e.g. {"PMC": 30.12} ).

```
public class RestletApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public synchronized Restlet createInboundRoot()
    {
        Router router = new Router(getContext());
        router.attach("/pmc/calculate", PMCResource.class);
        return router;
    }
}
```

I have written the function so far but am lost how to read the JSON input:

```
 public class PMCResource extends ServerResource
    {   
        @Post("JSON")
        public Representation post(Representation entity) throws ResourceException {
            try {
                if (entity.getMediaType().isCompatible(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                {
                    // Read JSON file and parse onto local variables

                    // Do processing & return a float value

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                getResponse().setStatus(Status.SERVER_ERROR_INTERNAL);
            }
        }
    }
```

**5 May 2016** - Edited the resource class

```
// Imports

public class PMCResource extends ServerResource
{
    static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PMCResource.class);

    @Override
    @Post("JSON")
    public Representation post(Representation entity) throws ResourceException
    {
        PMCMatrixDAO matrix = new PMCMatrixDAOImpl();
        JsonObjectBuilder response = Json.createObjectBuilder();

        try
        {
            if (entity.getMediaType().isCompatible(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            {
                InputStream is = new FileInputStream(getClass().getResource("/input.json").getFile());

                try (JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(is)) {
                    JsonObject obj = reader.readObject();
                    double result = matrix.calculatePMC(obj);
                    response.add("PMC", result);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            getResponse().setStatus(Status.SERVER_ERROR_INTERNAL);
        }

        return new StringRepresentation(response.build().toString());
    }
}
```

The Implementation class

```
public class PMCMatrixDAOImpl implements PMCMatrixDAO
{       
    public double calculatePMC(JsonObject obj) 
    {   
        int campaignID = obj.getInt("campaignID");
        int clientID = obj.getInt("clientID");
        int pmapID = obj.getInt("pmapID");
        String ward = obj.getString("ward");
        int age = obj.getInt("age");
        String attr1 = obj.getString("attr1");
        String attr2 = obj.getString("attr2");
        String attr3 = obj.getString("attr3");
        String attr4 = obj.getString("attr4");
        String attr5 = obj.getString("attr5");
        String attr6 = obj.getString("attr6");

        // SQL processing
        double dPMC = sqlQueryCall(...);

        return dPMC;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your JSON data come within your `Representation` entity?

Comment: I'm sorry @aribeiro, I don't really understand your question. Can you explain in layman term so this newbie can understand?

Comment: Well, do you simply want to *read* your JSON file, where you've placed your comment? Or you want to know how to execute a POST request with the contents mentioned?

Comment: @aribeiro After parsing the JSON file into local variables I will execute an SQL query to retrieve a value (decimal) from the database. I will then have to POST this value as JSON back to the client so they can display it on the portal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to parse your JSON file, and since you're using Maven I'll assume you have it on your classpath, you can do it using a `FileInputStream` or a `FileReader`. So, assuming your JSON file is called *input.json* and it is on the root of your *src/main/resources* folder, you can load it the following way:

- using a FileInputStream:

  ```
  InputStream is = new FileInputStream(getClass().getResource("/input.json").getFile());

  try (JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(is)) {
      // file processing is done here
  }
  ```
- using a FileReader:

  ```
  FileReader fr = new FileReader(getClass().getResource("/input.json").getFile());

  try (JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(fr)) {
      // file processing is done here
  }
  ```

Ok, so now that we have our `JsonReader` created, lets retrieve the contents of our JSON file:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(getClass().getResource("/input.json").getFile());

try (JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(is)) {
    JsonObject obj = reader.readObject();

    // retrieve JSON contents
    int campaingID = obj.getInt("campaignID");
    int clientID = obj.getInt("clientID");
    int pmapID = obj.getInt("pmapID");
    String ward = obj.getString("ward");
    int age = obj.getInt("age");
    String attr1 = obj.getString("attr1");
    String attr2 = obj.getString("attr2");
    String attr3 = obj.getString("attr3");
    String attr4 = obj.getString("attr4");
    String attr5 = obj.getString("attr5");
    String attr6 = obj.getString("attr6");
}
```

As an alternative of having several variables across your method, you could create a simple POJO, having those variable as attributes, and then [populate it](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html) using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson):

```
public class MyPojo {

    private int campaingID;
    private int clientID;
    private int pmapID;
    private String ward;
    private int age;
    private String attr1;
    private String attr2;
    private String attr3;
    private String attr4;
    private String attr5;
    private String attr6;

    // getters & setters
}
```

Finally, in order to send the response back to your client, you could do this:

```
JsonObject response = Json.createObjectBuilder().add("PMC", 30.12).build();

return new StringRepresentation(response.toString());
```

So, the entire solution could look like this:

```
@Override
@Post("JSON")
public Representation post(Representation entity) throws ResourceException {
    JsonObjectBuilder response = Json.createObjectBuilder();

    try {
        if (entity.getMediaType().isCompatible(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)) {
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(getClass().getResource("/input.json").getFile());

            try (JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(is)) {
                JsonObject obj = reader.readObject();

                // retrieve JSON contents
                int campaingID = obj.getInt("campaignID");
                int clientID = obj.getInt("clientID");
                int pmapID = obj.getInt("pmapID");
                String ward = obj.getString("ward");
                int age = obj.getInt("age");
                String attr1 = obj.getString("attr1");
                String attr2 = obj.getString("attr2");
                String attr3 = obj.getString("attr3");
                String attr4 = obj.getString("attr4");
                String attr5 = obj.getString("attr5");
                String attr6 = obj.getString("attr6");
            }

            // Do processing & execute your SQL query call here
            double result = sqlQueryCall(...);

            response.add("PMC", result);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        getResponse().setStatus(Status.SERVER_ERROR_INTERNAL);
    }

    return new StringRepresentation(response.build().toString());
}
```

As a side note, the `JsonReader` class belongs to the Java EE API which, for compiling purposes it's okay. Although, for running purposes, one [requires](https://jsonp.java.net/download.html) the declaration of a JSON-API implementation dependency in one's Maven project. For instance:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

---

Below is the way one can communicate to the REST web service through a client:

1. Create a simple POJO object that will contain the information to send, as mentioned above (`MyPojo`).
2. Your REST service would look something like this:

   ```
   public class PMCResource extends ServerResource {

       static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(RestletMain.class.getName());

       @Post("JSON")
       public Representation post(MyPojo entity) throws ResourceException {
           PMCMatrixDAO matrix = new PMCMatrixDAOImpl();
           JsonObjectBuilder response = Json.createObjectBuilder();

           try {
               double result = matrix.calculatePMC(entity);
               response.add("PMC", result);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               getResponse().setStatus(Status.SERVER_ERROR_INTERNAL);
           }

           return new StringRepresentation(response.build().toString());
       }
   }
   ```
3. Modify your `PMCMatrixDAOImpl` in order to process your POJO:

   ```
   public double calculatePMC(MyPojo pojo) {
       (...)
   }
   ```
4. Create a client that allows you to test your REST service:

   ```
   public class PMCResourceMain {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           // take into account the context-root, if exists, and path to your REST service
           ClientResource resource = new ClientResource("http://<host>:<port>");

           MyPojo myPojo = new MyPojo();
           myPojo.setCampaingID(1);
           myPojo.setClientID(1);
           myPojo.setPmapID(1);
           myPojo.setWard("1-Bedded (Private)");
           myPojo.setAge(20);
           myPojo.setAttr1("EXA1(A)");
           myPojo.setAttr2("EO");
           myPojo.setAttr3("11/02/2012");
           myPojo.setAttr4("SIN");
           myPojo.setAttr5("N");
           myPojo.setAttr6("Y");

           try {
               resource.post(myPojo, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).write(System.out);
           } catch (ResourceException | IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Full Restlet documentation can be found [here](https://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3).

Comment: Thanks for the sample program, really appreciate that. I decided to pass the entire JSON object to the `Implementation` class to retrieve the contents and do all the processing.

Since the client is the one sending the JSON file over does that mean I have to instruct them on where to save the JSON file or I just need to create an empty JSON file and instruct them to write to it whenever needed?

Lastly, can you also show me how to write a simple client class to test this out?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by *decided to pass the entire JSON object to the `Implementation` class* nor I understand the part *the client is the one sending the JSON file over*. Is it possible for you to update your original post (OP) with what you intend to achieve? :)

Comment: Sorry if I confuse you, probably I am not using the right syntax to explain it. I have edited my OP to reflect this. Basically I am trying to avoid doing any processing on the representation class.

Comment: I am working on a collaboration project. The software vendor is responsible for designing the member portal (where member can register with details) while I am in charge of doing the calculation part. Vendor will then pass all the relevant info needed for the calculation as a JSON file (through a webservice). I'll pick up the JSON, read it, do processing and finally return a value so it can be displayed on the portal.

Comment: I have completed the other simpler webservices where only minimal input is required. I constructed URI such as `http://localhost:9090/fwd-PMAP/pmap/client/1` then I use `getRequestAttributes()` to retrieve the value directly from the URI, do processing and return the value. However, for this particular webservice, since there are a lot of info needed it's not recommended to use the same approach (the URI will be really looonnngggg). Vendor then suggested JSON and that's when I get lost. :p

Comment: Based on current codes my program is working fine to retrieve the PMC value from the database. However, it always read the `input.json` file in the `src/main/resources`. How can I make it read the JSON file the client sent through the webservice?

Comment: `InputStream is = new FileInputStream(getClass().getResource("/input.json").getFile())`
This line is supposed to read from a physical file in src/main/resources folder. How can I read from URI instead?

Comment: Why should you read it from a URI?! Your *Vendor* should invoke your REST web service through a POST request, passing you your JSON in the form of an object, as I've mentioned above. You should not *read* your JSON.

Comment: It was a result of bad business decision and I have to live with it. I've figured it out and just completed the program. I'll accept your answer since you've been really helpful in guiding me along the way. Thanks @aribeiro!

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of those who landed in the same situation as me, here's my solution:

Resource class

```
@Override
@Post("JSON")
public Representation post(Representation entity) throws ResourceException
{
    PMCMatrixDAO matrix = new PMCMatrixDAOImpl();
    JsonObjectBuilder response = Json.createObjectBuilder();

    try {
        String json = entity.getText(); // Get JSON input from client
        Map<String, Object> map = JsonUtils.toMap(json); // Convert input into Map
        double result = matrix.calculatePMC(map);
        response.add("PMC", result);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(this.getClass() + " - IOException - " + e);
        getResponse().setStatus(Status.SERVER_ERROR_INTERNAL);
    }

    return new StringRepresentation(response.build().toString());       
}
```

JSON conversion utility class

```
public class JsonUtils {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JsonUtils.class);

    private JsonUtils() {
    }

    public static String toJson(Object object) {
        String jsonString = null;

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return jsonString;
    }

    public static Map<String, Object> toMap(String jsonString) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            map = mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return map;
    }
}
```

And the implementation class which handles all the processing

```
public class PMCMatrixDAOImpl implements PMCMatrixDAO
{       
    public double calculatePMC(Map<String, Object> map) 
    {   
        int campaignID  = (int) map.get("campaignID");
        int clientID    = (int) map.get("clientID");
        int pmapID      = (int) map.get("pmapID");
        String ward     = (String) map.get("ward");
        int age         = (int) map.get("age");
        String attr1 = (String) map.get("attr1");
        String attr2 = (String) map.get("attr2");
        String attr3 = (String) map.get("attr3");
        String attr4 = (String) map.get("attr4");
        String attr5 = (String) map.get("attr5");
        String attr6 = (String) map.get("attr6");

        // SQL processing
        double dPMC = sqlQueryCall(...);

        return dPMC;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution seems okay! :) But, taking into account the approach you've followed, I think you'll be able to improve it a little more. Try dropping your JSON conversion utility class, and your `Representation` argument, and force the usage of a POJO. It will make your code way cleaner and less error prone.